# Dijkstra's Algo: no way to visit all vertices without visiting a vertex twice?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

[image: Network]

I was learning about Dijkstra's Algorithm and came across a question with network as shown above. The question states that the starting vertex is 1 and the shortest paths should be found with Dijkstra's algorithm.
If my understanding is correct, we should choose the succeeding vertex j with the smallest d[j], which in this case for vertex 1, the succeeding vertex with smallest distance is vertex 4, d[4] = 1.
However, if vertex 4 is chosen, then there is no way to visit vertex 2 or 5 without visiting the same vertex twice.
I am not sure if my understanding is wrong or if there is an error in this question. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you!

Comment: The notion of "visited" in Dijkstra's algorithm is different than the notion of "visited" in other path-finding algorithms. In Dijkstra's, node 1 is marked as visited after updating the distances to all of its neighbors. So even though the algorithm updates the distance to node 5 while processing node 1, node 5 has not been "visited".

Answer (score 0):

I think your misunderstanding is the concept of "choosing 4 next". The output of Dijkstra's is not a single path that goes over all vertices -- [it's a shortest path tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree). So choosing 4 doesn't mean all the shortest paths will have to contain vertex 4.

Going forward with the algorithm, you'll calculate the following shortest path tree:

[image: dijkstra output]

Which will show that to get to vertex 2 from 1, shortest path is of length 4, and is achieved by jumping directly from 1.